# Is there a way to use the jQuery ThemeRoller with ExtJS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, extjs, themes, themeroller

We are using jQuery and ExtJS in a project.  ExtJS's custom theming capabilities are very weak and I would LOVE to utilize the jQuery theming engine with Ext.  Does such a thing exist or would it be strictly manual and painful process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a manual/painful process, the themes/classes are built specifically for/with the jQuery UI widgets (and themeroller is updated when jQuery UI is, for new classes and such).

There are some helpful options out there though, like [the ExtJS Color theme changer](http://playground.ideashs.com/themescolor/) and [the ExtJS theme generator](https://github.com/extjs/extjs-theme).

Comment: I tried the color theme generator but it is too difficult to get what I want.  I may try the Ruby one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Ext JS 4 (coming Q1 2011) the theming has been re-written from the ground up and is based on SASS templates and CSS3 now.  Supposedly (I have not yet used it) it's going to be much, much easier to customize.  FYI.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Hopefully by then we will abandon Ext and use only jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Simple online Theme Builder for ExtJS 3.x.](http://extbuilder.dynalias.com)